# How to manually update?

Tags: macos, software-update, auto-update

Obviously I'm online and able to connect to apple.com and other websites.
*System Updates* think I'm offline for some *2-trillion$* reason.

[image]

Is there a way to trigger a manual update?

Answer (score 1):

Being connected to the internet is one step, next is

```
softwareupdate --all --install
```

Should that fail, I would test APNS notifications to see if your network may be blocking outbound and inbound traffic to Apple servers.

- https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/push-diagnostics/
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210060

The second link explains what network ranges and ports have to be free of interference. One typical situation is a network is performing one of MITM attack / HTTPS Interception / SSL Inspection of the traffic between your device and Apple, rendering the secure connections invalid.

This can also just result from [Apple services are in an error condition](https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/) or your network or OS has issues. I test that with a [command line invocation if the software update tool](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/338297/5472).

You can then run the full installer to accomplish your update or see errors why it’s not progressing in many cases.